# How do I set/limit a number of retry attempts in RabbitMQ when sending a message if it fails?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I am using RabbitMQ and I have a queue that holds messages.  If a message fails, 3 attempts are made. I would like to limit the number of times to 1, that I can requeue the message to be sent again.  Is there any other way in which I can approach this? Thanks in advance.

```
  bindings:
    documentrequest-policyinqadapter:
      destination: PI-DocumentRequestService-AdapterService-Exchange
      group: dcsnt-policyinquiryadapter-documentrequest-processessor
  rabbit:
    bindings:
      documentrequest-policyinqadapter:
        producer:
          routing-key-expression: headers['events-type']
        consumer:
          autoBindDlq: true
          republishToDlq: true
          default-requeue-rejected: false
          bindingRoutingKey: documentrequest.adapter.*.*.*.policyinq.req
          deadLetterQueueName: pi-adapter-dead-letter-queue
          deadLetterExchange: PI-DocumentRequestService-AdapterService-Exchange-dlx
          deadLetterRoutingKey: documentrequest.adapter.*.*.*.policyinq.req
          maxAttempts: 1
          maxConcurrency: 10
```

Answer (score 0):

`maxAttempts` is a consumer binding property that is common to all binders.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.2/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_consumer_properties

You have it defined as a rabbit-specific binding property.

Move it up.